# Cucumber js then not throwing failure

Tags: javascript, chai, cucumberjs

I'm writing a small test in cucumber.js

```
defineSupportCode(function({Given, When, Then}){
Given(/^I have a valid github username $/, function(callback){
    githubUserName = 'test';
    callback();
});

When('I call username api', function(callback){
    let url = githubUrl+githubUserName;
    let response;
    var data;
    githubResponse = fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {return json});
    callback();
});

Then('I get userdetails', function(){
    githubResponse.then(function(data){
        console.log(data.name);
        expect(data.name).to.equal("abc");
    });
});
```

});

Now when I run the test it keeps passing. I even tried have a callback in Then, but still it keeps passing, although the expect is throwing an exception.

Am I missing any handler anywhere. I'm a total novice for this style of programming.

Comment: Not sure what your "fetch" function does, but assuming your code does what you think it does, you are missing a return in your "then" step: `return githubResponse.then...`. Without a return cucumber will end the function without waiting for the call to execute and complete, and thus it will always succeed.

Answer (score 1):

So perhaps the problem is that the [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method) for fetch says that it does not fail when there is a 404. [So perhaps you need to write a wrapper around it to deal with this](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/155). Here is my version:

```
function myFetch(url, options) {
  if (options == null) options = {};
  return fetch(url, options).then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return Promise.resolve(response);
    } else {
      var error = {};
      error.response = response;
      error.status = response.status;
      return Promise.reject(error);
  }
});
}

Now when you call the "then" you can write a catch to find your 404:

fetchPromise.then(function(response) { 
  console.log(response.status); })
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("problem: ", error.status); 
});
```

I have mocked this up in the browser console only so I am not certain this is perfect. Please let me know if this helps or what you did to solve it.